# Tensorflow-gpu not detecting GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I have tensorflow-gpu version 2.2.0 installed with Anaconda in python 3.7.4, but my code always runs on CPU and It's not able to detect my GPU.

```
physical_devices= tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(len(physical_devices))
>>> 0
```

When I run this:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 6159543114609950707
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 4043157374881641271
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 1519736160969870434
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

The XLA_GPU:0 corresponds to the integrated graphics that runs on CPU, because I have tested running my code under *with tf.device('/GPU:0'):* and Task Manager shows only CPU usage.

I checked in my NVIDIA Control Panel ->  System Information -> Components and under 3D Settings I have NVCUDA64.dll described as NVIDIA CUDA 11.0.208 Driver.

Up to this moment I haven't tried reinstalled tensorflow-gpu, expecting there could be something else that has to be done before.

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be that tf 2.2 doesn't support your current CUDA version. Though, I thought CUDA would be backwards compatible.

Comment: I downgraded to 10.1 and got the corresponding cuDNN version but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe 11.0 will work with tensorflow. You need 10.1. I have an RTX2070 and the driver version that work for that is 432.00. Go to the NVIDIA site and try to find a 10.1 compatible driver and  install it. IF you used CONDA to install tensorflow then it should have installed the 10.1 CUDA toolkit and the compatible version of Cudnn.

Comment: I followed the instructions and installed CUDA 10.1. Then I looked for the respective cuDNN for that version and followed the installing instructions, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: I think you need to change you GPU card DRIVER to a driver compatible with 10.1.

Comment: Do you know what card driver version should I install?My current is 451.67

Comment: it depends om what GPU card you have. Mine is an RTX2070 and the driver version is 432.00

Answer (score 3):

My own answer. Finally it worked:

I had to download CUDA 10.1 and then cuDNN 7.6.5 for that version.

Thanks to @Gerry P and @Richard X

Comment: Thank you all, I had the same issue, by installing cuDNN it works!

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed tensorflow 2.7 and it worked fine. Here is my configuration:
CUDA: 11.5, CUDNN: 8.3, TENSORFLOW: 2.7, PYTHON: 3.9.9, GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1060, DRIVER VERSION: 497.29

I did not use Conda (even though it is very convenient but it results in a lot of version conflicts). I installed everything manually on Windows 10 like below. So, if anyone looking for instructions in or after Jan 2022:

1. Install python b/w 3.90 - 3.9.9 (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-399/)
2. Install cuda tool kit (Check compatibility with your GPU) ([https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archiv](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive)e)
3. Install cudnn and make sure it is compatible with the cuda version installed above (https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

**Note: don't forget to install zlib when following instructions from the link above ([https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu))*

4. Make sure the bin of both cuda and cudnn are on the PATH (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin), (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.3.1.22_cuda11.5-archive\bin)
5. Install tensorflow (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)
   Use pip3 when installing for python3+
6. If you want to create Jupyter notebooks then install jupyter "pip3 install jupyterlab" (https://jupyter.org/install)
7. Finally, restart your machine or atleast restart the shell
8. Run the following from python REPL, you should get 1 or more

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf 
>
> print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check Tensorflow's documentation for matching version with CUDA and cuDNN:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Make sure you get them correct. Otherwise they will not work.